# Why is reloadData() not working in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I'm trying to download a set of images from Parse.com into a UICollectionView. Everything works except for the reloadData() function. In the app, I can hit the back button and re-enter the UICollectionView and all of the images are there. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong with the reloadData() function.

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()

class CollectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBAction func xy1Button(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func xy2Button(sender: AnyObject) {

        var downloadImages = PFQuery(className: "XY2")
        downloadImages.whereKey("Expansion", equalTo: "XY2")
        downloadImages.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) cards.")
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        imageFiles.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ^{
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            });
                        //ERROR BREAKPOINT HERE:'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)'
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }    
      }
}   
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageFiles.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
    //cell.cardsImg.image = UIImage(named: cards[indexPath.row] as String)
    //return cell
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            cell.cardsImg.image = image
        }


    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `self.collectionView`?

Comment: Run it in the main_queue like sahara says :) This isn't always very intuitive but usually when UI changes don't update or take a long time to update then try running the code in the main queue

Comment: You don't seem to have an outlet to the `collectionView`, and therefore there is no such property `self.collectionView`. You don't need one for the delegate functions you have defined, as it is passed in as a parameter, but to call reloadData(), you do.

Comment: Yeah, you probably used a Nib or Storyboard, make sure your IBOutlet collectionView is linked to the Nib/Storyboard file. And do the reload on the main thread

Comment: CollectionCollectionViewController probably should be a subclass of UICollectionViewController instead of UIViewController.

Comment: You need an instance variable or a UICollectionViewController subclass. Otherwise self.collectionView is meaningless.

Answer (score 9):

The `reloadData` need to be executed in main thread to update the UI. You can try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
});
```

And as @Grimxn suggested, you should check if your `collectionView` IBOutlet is connected in storyboard or xib file.

Comment: He said that if he go back and re-enter the screen, the collection view is updated. So I think he already set the outlet up. Anyway thank for you comment. I will update the answer.

Comment: ... which is what would happen if he had no outlet. The delegate will still supply the data, even if he has no outlet, he just can't call reloadData() himself, he has to rely on the system reloading the collection for him...

Comment: According to https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on, all Parse completion blocks *are* called on the background thread. And how would this explain a *compiler error* `'Cannot invoke 'reloadData()' with no arguments'` ?

Comment: I'm still having trouble. Where exactly should I put this code?

Comment: You put it in the right place. Can you show me where do you define self.collectionView?

Comment: I managed to use ``DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { code })`` but i still see no results in ``collectionView(_ :indexPath: )`` thow ``numberOfSections(collectionView:) -> Int`` is able to return the correct number of rows i am creating. I am putting my data in a disctionary of arrays: ``    var usersPayments:[String:[String]] = ["Name":["Amount"]]
``

Answer (score 0):

Even though I meant to do this, I simply forgot, and I didn't see it in your code so it might be your issue too. I never set the ViewController as the collectionView.delegate and collectionView.dataSource

I've used Image Pickers, TableViews, and other UI components which require the delegate, but simply overlooked it this time.

This is my code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func setData(data: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    /* DELEGATE METHODS
    .........
    END DELEGATE METHODS */
}
```